# Permutation and Combination Problem including a set of digits and a condition.

Tags: combinatorics

Four-digit numbers will be written using the numbers $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7$.

a) How many different 4-digit numbers can be written using the above digits (Repetition not allowed)?

b) How many such numbers are there between $4000$ and $6000$ (Repetition not allowed)?

Please verify these answers and correct me where I am wrong, I don't know the answers.

My Try:

Total number of choices = $8 \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$

a) $7\times7\times6\times5 = 1470$.
Because excluding $0$ from the first place leaves me with 7 choices to be filled in the thousandth position, when moving to the hundredth position, $0$ again becomes an option so I wrote $7$ again and I proceeded further with $6$ because the previous 2 positions covered 2 choices I followed the same process for last digit.

b) $2\times6\times5\times4$.
 Because I fixed $4$, $5$ at thousandth place and hence I was left with $6$ choices for next digit and so on.

Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: You haven't stated explicitly whether your numbers are allowed to repeat digits.  Please **edit the question** to clarify this point.

Comment: In part (a), are you assuming digits can't be repeated?

Comment: Assuming 4 distinct digits is intended: In (b), there are still 7 choices for the hundreds digit. The thousands digit is either 4 or 5, but not both at the same time.

Comment: Start with something simple ; it is not clearly said that numbers starting with 0 are excluded. So include them. Eventually, in a second step, you will exclude them. Counting all 4-digits numbers, including those starting with 0 is simple. Exclude numbers starting with 0 is simple.  Counting directly in one single formula all 4-digits numbers, excluding those starting with 0 is more complexe.  You can also try another exercice, with 10 digits instead of 8. When we have 10 digits, we have 2000 (or 2001) numbers between 4000 and 6000. If you apply your logic, do you find 2000 or 2001 ?

Comment: since the OP doesn't count repetition in the first case, we are free to assume repetition is not allowed.

Comment: also, the b part should be $2\times7\times6\times5$ because even though you have fixed $4,5$ to the first place, you still have $7$ choices for the next as you can use the one of the two you haven't chosen.

Comment: @user2661923 from the first example, the OP clearly shows repetition is not allowed : so 4000 is as unacceptable as 6000.

Comment: @DS Good point.  I deleted my previous comment.

Comment: OP has posted a formula (random formula from the lesson). You and me, we know that this formula is more or less valid when we exclude duplicates. But is it enough to conclude that the real objective was to exclude duplicates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, before answering your question, I must discuss the following points:

1. Your first part *can* be correct, but the second part is *certainly* wrong. The first part will be correct only if the repetition of digits *is not* allowed. The question does not explicitly state this.
2. When repetition *is* allowed, there would be $7\times8\times8\times8$ numbers. This is because the first place has $7$ choices ($0$ not allowed), but the next places all have $8$ choices since you can repeat the digits. Let's say you have the digits $1,2,3$ and want to make 3-digit numbers. If repetition is not allowed, this is $3\times2\times1=6$. The six numbers are $123,132,213,231,312,321$. If repetitions are allowed, the number increases to $3\times3\times3 = 27$. They are $111,112,113,121,122,123,131,132,133,211,212,213,221,222,223,231,232,233,311,312,313,321,322,323,331,332,333$
3. Since you used the repetition not allowed approach in the a) part, I'm going to assume repetition is not allowed.

By that assumption, the first part is correct but the second is wrong. Let's see this step by step:

For the first place, you can choose two digits ($4$ or $5$). But you only choose $1$ of them. So you have $7$ choices for the next place, $6$ for the third and $5$ for the last, giving you $2\times7\times6\times5$. 
To get an intuition on why this is so, let us divide our work. Say the first digit is $4$. You have $7$ options for the next place - $0,1,2,3,\color{green}5,6,7$, six for the next, five for the last. So, you have $7\times6\times5$ numbers for this case. Now, suppose the first digit is a $5$. You have $7$ choices for the second place: $0,1,2,3,\color{green}4,6,7$, six choices for the next digit and five for the last. Again, you get $7\times6\times5$. Adding to get the total cases, we have $7\times6\times5+7\times6\times5 = 2\times7\times6\times5$, the same answer.
Here is a simpler example. Suppose you can use all $10$ digits (without repetition). How many two-digit numbers can you form between $40$ and $59$ (both included)? We can easily see, by counting, that the answer is $18$ - all numbers from $40$ to $59$ except $44$ and $55$. Another way is, we have $2$ choices for the first place ($4$ or $5$). By your logic, we have only $8$ choices for the second, giving $2\times8 = 16$, which is incorrect. This has the same error discussed above. Instead, if you consider $9$ choices for the second place, you get the correct answer: $2\times9=18$.
I hope this rant helped you to understand the mistake.

Comment: Thank You for that detailed clarification. I also apologize for not stating whether repetition is allowed or not. You made my day!